# Блокировки в memcache

Tags: memcache, php

Добрый день.

Есть кеш с пользователями и сообщениями для них, например:

```
 User_1['{'from':'User_55','data':'Привет'}']
```

Когда User_55 пишет сообщение для User_1, то записываем в кеш для User_1, а пользователь User_1 периодически проверяет кеш, и если там что-то новое, то работаем с этим и очищаем кеш.
Но... если много человек начнут слать сообщения к одному человеку, надо как-то блокировать memcache.

Для файла делаю подобное с flock:

```
while ((time() - $time) < 30) {
            if ($data = file_get_contents('sockets/'.$sock)) {
                $f = fopen('sockets/'.$sock, 'r+b') or die('socket not found');
                flock($f, LOCK_EX);
                ftruncate($f, 0);
                fwrite($f, '');
                fclose($f);
                $data = trim($data, "\r\n");
                foreach (explode("\r\n", $data) as $action) {
                    self::$actions[] = $action;
                }
                self::Send();
            }
            sleep(1);
        }
```

А как быть с кешем? Можете подсказать конкретный пример?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

memcache не предназначен для конкурирующих запросов, единственное,  что там есть, - это атомарные операции инкремента/декремента.

У вас ошибка в архитектуре, в данном случае нужно или переходить на key-value хранилище, которое обеспечивает работу с конкурирующими запросами, или организовать очередь.

Comment: @jenikok Можно организовать [оптимистическую блокировку](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%28%D0%A1%D0%A3%D0%91%D0%94%29) на уровне бизнес-логики - некая абстракция над memcached. Могу посоветовать [свой инструмент](https://github.com/romeOz/rock-cache). Правда, накладных расходов не избежать - 2 запроса вместо одного + нет возможности использовать нативных multi-методов: `getMulti()`, `setMulti()`,...